# How to get a white background to remain white in mobile & gmail/outlook dark mode - Email HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, pardot

I am having issues with the background disappearing - not inverting, just fully going transparent. Its happening on mobile across gmail, outlook and seems to happen on outlook for desktop dark mode too.

I've tried changing the colour to a background image, no success
tried making an entire mobile version of the row, no success

*update: the below code seems to have fixed the mobile menu bar but not the gmail or outlook issues, and the footer bar is still inverting on mobile*

See the email code below:

Menu Header Bar:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-2" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #fff; background-image: url(https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/Header%20Background.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; border-bottom: 5px solid #06f; border-radius: 0; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="66.66666666666667%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" class="image_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad">
                                                <div align="left" class="alignment" style="line-height:10px"><a href="https://blackbull.com" style="outline:none" tabindex="-1" target="_blank"><img class="fullWidth" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/rebrand-BB_full-logo.png" style="height: auto; display: block; border: 0; max-width: 167px; width: 100%;" width="167"></a></div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="column column-2" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="20%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="button_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad">
                                                <div align="center" class="alignment"><!--[if mso]><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://secure.blackbull.com/" style="height:28px;width:62px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="18%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#ffffff"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px"><center style="color:#000000; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:15px"><![endif]--><a href="https://secure.blackbull.com/" style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#000000;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;width:auto;border-top:0px solid transparent;font-weight:600;border-right:0px solid transparent;border-bottom:0px solid transparent;border-left:0px solid transparent;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-family:'Readex Pro','Arial';font-size:15px;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;white-space: nowrap;" target="_blank"><span style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;"><span style="word-break: break-word; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap">Login</span></span></a><!--[if mso]></center></v:textbox></v:roundrect><![endif]--></div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="column column-3" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="20%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="button_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad">
                                                <div align="center" class="alignment"><!--[if mso]><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://secure.blackbull.com/dashboard/wallet/add-funds?lang=en" style="height:28px;width:57px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="18%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#ffffff"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px"><center style="color:#000000; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:15px"><![endif]--><a href="https://secure.blackbull.com/dashboard/wallet/add-funds?lang=en" style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#000000;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;width:auto;border-top:0px solid transparent;font-weight:600;border-right:0px solid transparent;border-bottom:0px solid transparent;border-left:0px solid transparent;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-family:'Readex Pro','Arial';font-size:15px;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;" target="_blank"><span style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;"><span style="word-break: break-word; line-height: 18px;white-space: nowrap;">Fund</span></span></a><!--[if mso]></center></v:textbox></v:roundrect><![endif]--></div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Further Questions Contact Us Bar:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-7 mobile_hide" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-size: auto;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #000; background-color: #1a58d3; background-image: url(https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/question%20section%20backdrop.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; border-radius: 0; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 50px; padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 50px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="41.666666666666664%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="paragraph_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad">
                                                <div style="color:#fff;direction:ltr;font-family:'Readex Pro','Arial';font-size:19px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:left;mso-line-height-alt:22.8px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 0;"><strong>Any questions?</strong><br>
                                                <strong>Get in touch.</strong></p>
                                                </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="column column-2" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="58.333333333333336%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="icons_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad" style="vertical-align: middle; color: #000000; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-bottom: 35px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 35px; text-align: right;">
                                                <table align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="alignment" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="tel:+6495585142" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/call-us-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="https://blackbull.com/en/" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/live_chat-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="https://blackbull.com/en/" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/visit-web-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px;" class=""><a href="mailto:support@blackbullmarkets.com?subject=" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/mail-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-8 desktop_hide" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden; background-size: auto;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden; color: #000; background-color: #06f; background-size: auto; border-radius: 0; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: top; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="paragraph_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad">
                                                <div style="color:#fff;direction:ltr;font-family:'Readex Pro','Arial';font-size:19px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:left;mso-line-height-alt:22.8px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 0;">Any Questions?<br>
                                                Get in touch.</p>
                                                </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-9 desktop_hide" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden; background-size: auto;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden; color: #000; background-color: #000; background-image: url(https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/blackbackground.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; border-radius: 0; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: left; font-weight: 400; background-color: #000000; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: top; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="icons_block block-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden;" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad" style="vertical-align: middle; color: #000000; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 35px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 35px; text-align: center;">
                                                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="alignment" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-hide: all; max-height: 0; display: none; overflow: hidden;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="+6495585142" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/call-us-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="https://blackbull.com" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/live_chat-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" class=""><a href="https://blackbull.com" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/visit-web-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 10px;" class=""><a href="support@blackbull.com" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_self"><img align="center" class="icon" height="32" src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/867844_851980/mail-32.png" style="height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" width="32"></a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you want help with. Your question is too open ended and requires a lot of guesswork when you don't show any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail apps work with a background image approach. That is, for dark mode- but that's not what you're talking about.

There is a recent issue that may be affecting some users where background images stop working. This is a bug with Gmail webmail, and they are apparently fixing it. In the meantime, using the *attribute* background will work, i.e. `background="https://path.to/image"`. See https://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-rolling-out-changes-that-strip-background-image-css/?r=email for more details.

Outlook dark mode is not working because background images are not supported via the normal method. You have to use VML. However, if you do use VML, images on Windows Mail (ever so slightly different to Outlook, but basically the same) within that section do not appear. (There are lots of answers already on how to make background images in Outlook work.) There are very complicated ways of potentially making it work for Windows Mail, but we don't bother any more so I'd have to hunt around for it. Comment if you want me to expand on that.